# how to get active/current run testNG xml file name

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, testng, browser-automation

Can anyone faced a requirement of reading active TestNG file in your automation.?

I have scenario of getting 'current running' TestNG' file name to read values inside *.xml file.

I have tried following:

```
XmlTest test = context.getCurrentXmlTest();
String testtt = context.getName();
```

But it returns active test method name only not file name. So I am looking for a solution, which can return 'file name' of my testNG xml.

Comment: Hi,
I found the resolution for my above requirement :
**XmlSuite suiteName = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite();**
**suiteName.getFileName();**